# how to style an SVG image to change a color with a delay

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-transitions, mix-blend-mode

got a svg that swiches between coloroverlays, the style looks like this

```
.wsf-tshirt{fill:#fff;mix-blend-mode: multiply;}
```

and the java string that's included looks like this:

```
$('.wsf-tshirt').css({fill: '#field(391)', 'mix-blend-mode': 'multiply'});
```

Q: what elements do I add to make the transition last for a second-ish ?

Comment: `java` is not same as `javascript`, also looks like you are using `jQuery` as well, so update your tags to match that

Comment: Do you mean change colour, then change back after a second?

Comment: well, building a online store, and I need to style the transition-property that is instent right now, here's the project https://persienner.online/product/linknap/ I\m kind of new to any coding - how the shift between the two colors run smoothly or maybe with a gradiant effect or something ..